# SQL0103 The numeric literal "00XAB" is not valid SQLSTATE = 42604

Tags: sql, db2

I want to insert string for instance '7000,21,00XYZ, ABC'
when I use this as an insert into a table, I get the error as mentioned, please help me with this for DB2.
I am able to insert this when I do
**INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1(COLUMN1)
(SELECT statement)**

But this is not working for Dynamic Sql.

Comment: Show the real insert statement,, and show the target-column Db2-datatype,  and also show the full plain-text error message including any additional numbers or codes. Mention the codepage of your Db2-database, along with the Db2-platform (z/os, i series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong dynamic sql use probably.
Consider the following example.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
SET  SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
    DECLARE V_STR VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT '7000,21,00XYZ, ABC';
    DECLARE V_STMT VARCHAR (100);
    DECLARE V_CNT INT;
    -- Incorrect use of a string constant:
    -- SET V_STMT = 'SET ? = (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM (VALUES ' || V_STR || '))';
    -- Correct use of a string constant:
    SET V_STMT = 'SET ? = (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM (VALUES ''' || V_STR || '''))';
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_STMT);
    PREPARE S1 FROM V_STMT;
    EXECUTE S1 INTO V_CNT;
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CNT: ' || V_CNT);
END@

SET  SERVEROUTPUT OFF@
```

If you forgot to wrap your string constant into single quotes and constructed an incorrect statement:

```
SET ? = (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM (VALUES 7000,21,00XYZ, ABC))
```

instead of the correct one:

```
SET ? = (SELECT COUNT (1) FROM (VALUES '7000,21,00XYZ, ABC'))
```

then you get the `SQL0103N` error as you showed: Db2 assumes that `VALUES 7000,21,00XYZ, ABC` is a table of a single column and 4 values, and since the literal `00XYZ` starts from a number, then it's an attempt to provide a numeric constant which is not valid, of course.